# Ubuntu x86 10.10 terminal

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal

I just downloaded a Ubuntu v10.10 vmware image for Windows.  I'm trying to install a web application that can only run on Linux MySQL, Apache and PHP.  How do I open a terminal in Ubuntu?

Comment: Woops.. found it.  Accessories > Terminal.  Sorry for such an easy question.  I was eager to try the UNIX stack exchange forum ;-)  I haven't used Linux in 7 years.

Comment: Good to hear. You can post the solution as an answer and accept it ([click the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) next to the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: Accessories > Terminal
 ;-)

Comment: I guess I have to wait 8 hours to answer my own.. but I'll probably forget.